# SELinux: cannot chcon script with cifs_t context

Tags: centos, selinux

I keep getting an `'Operation not supported'` message when trying to update the security context type of my cifs mount. I'm using logrotate to push logs off my server to a network location but the context of the script thats execute on the cifs mount is `'system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0'`

Here are the mount flags for my cifs folder:

```
(rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=cifsuser,domain=.,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=10.1.3.97,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,rsize=61440,wsize=16580,actimeo=1)
```

I had my logrotate running from a cron.hourly and everytime it tried to move files to this mount I would get a selinux policy error. I tried to run the following to resolve:

```
sealert -l b9263b3e-d2f9-4b33-ba48-af9b3b7695fd
grep logrotate /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
semodule -i mypol.pp
```

But I still have problems and it no longer gives me the sealert errors in /var/log/messages. Checking my /var/log/audit/audit.log logs I see this:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1474114505.460:25005): arch=c000003e syscall=21 success=no exit=-13 a0=10f33a0 a1=4 a2=7ffd34025160 a3=7ffd34025080 items=0 ppid=16240 pid=16241 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=2773 comm="sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1474114506.695:25006): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=16386 comm="sh" name="archive_logs.sh" dev="cifs" ino=60235645016091360 scontext=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I expanded the policy given its a bug. Install the RPM `selinux-devel` if not already present and then paste this content into a file called `mylogrotate.te`.

```
policy_module(mylogrotate, 1.0.0)

require {
  type logrotate_t;
  type cifs_t;
}

gen_tunable(logrotate_use_cifs, false)

tunable_policy(`logrotate_use_cifs',`
  fs_read_cifs_files(logrotate_t)
')
```

After which, do the following:

```
$ make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile load
$ semanage boolean --modify --off logrotate_use_cifs
```

That should allow policy to read the cifs files.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the AVC denial message with `audit2allow`, I get:

```
$ echo 'type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1474114505.460:25005): arch=c000003e syscall=21 success=no exit=-13 a0=10f33a0 a1=4 a2=7ffd34025160 a3=7ffd34025080 items=0 ppid=16240 pid=16241 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=2773 comm="sh" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null) \
        type=AVC msg=audit(1474114506.695:25006): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=16386 comm="sh" name="archive_logs.sh" dev="cifs" ino=60235645016091360 scontext=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=file' \
| audit2allow

#============= logrotate_t ==============
allow logrotate_t cifs_t:file read;
```

My guess is that the CIFS mount is not correctly labelled, as the policy allows `logrotate` to read from `cifs_t` labelled files, as shown by `sesearch`:

```
$ sesearch -s logrotate_t -t cifs_t -p read --allow -c dir 
Found 1 semantic av rules:
  allow logrotate_t cifs_t : dir { ioctl read getattr lock search open } ;
```

Comment: I think the policy is flawed, as a broader search shows that it only allows these operations on _directories_, but not _files_.

Comment: Given there is a boolean on my build of this for `logrotate_use_nfs` that does read from NFS and not for cifs, I suspect this is a oversight in policy too.